# SQL duplicate key error - delete row and create new row vs. update row

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I'm using Azure SQL and have a client-service that logs the user's location and data every 30 minutes. It uploads this data from the client to the database, but I'm getting errors.

I have this stored procedure:

```
INSERT INTO ThisIsMyTable(UserID, Latitude, Longitude)
VALUES (@UserID, @Latitude, @Longitude)
```

But when the same user's client uploads data with the same `UserID` I'm getting the following error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PrimaryKey_asdad'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ThisIsMyTable'. The duplicate key value
>   is (TheUsersUserID). The statement has been terminated.

How can I change the stored procedure and check if the key already exists, and if so - update the lat/lon.. Or would be deleting the row and create a new one be better?

Niels

Comment: There is a MERGE statement that may be beneficial to use here. I believe its supported in Azure SQL

Comment: How would I use this in regards to the above script? My SQL knowledge is quite limited. What does merge doe.. basically updating the old values with the new?

Comment: @Niels - Based on the accepted answer, there is something inherently wrong with the application if the `UserID` cannot be used more than one time for a database insert. RE: "...logs the user's location and data every 30 minutes" - if this is the case, the `UserID` can only be inserted once and then overwritten every 30 minutes rather than a new record being created every 30 minutes. If this is not the desired behavior, then most likely either the `ThisIsMyTable` is incorrectly defined to have the `UserID` column defined as a PK, or the `TheUsersUserID` is not being defined/set correctly.

Comment: Not really.. I only need the latest Lat/Lon, and do not want to keep ALL records (privacy + size of DB + no need for it really). Replacing the row, or updating it with the latest data is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if exists (select 1 from ThisIsMyTable where UserID = @UserID)

   update ThisIsMyTable 
   set latitude = @latitude, longitude = @longitude 
   where UserID = @UserID

else

   INSERT INTO ThisIsMyTable (UserID, Latitude, Longitude)
   VALUES (@UserID, @Latitude, @Longitude)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MERGE INTO ThisIsMyTable AS Target
USING (VALUES (@UserID,@Latitude, @Longitude)
       AS Source (UserID, Lat, Long)
ON Target.UserID = Source.UserID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET Latitude = Source.Lat, Longitude=Source.Long
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (UserID, Latitude, Longitude) VALUES (UserID, Lat, Long)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge statement in SQL, more details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx